# Header icon, title and navbar spill out of header container on screen resize

Tags: html, css

On image resize my header icon, title and navbar spill out of my header, which is set to occupy 10% of screen height. I've attempted setting element heights in the header div but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Image (icon spilling out of header) and code below. Let me know if can clarify further.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

```css
.banner {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner p {
  font-family: "Gentium Basic";
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.banner img {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.ban1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>
      <img src=UpYours.png height=1%>
      <span class="ban1" style=color:grey>What</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">me</a>
    <a href="#">you</a>
    <a href="#">what</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">today</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the screenshot piece you posted your desired behavior? Post more descriptive screenshots please, or reproduce your issue within a sandbox like http://codepen.io/pen (you can use http://placehold.it/50x50 for a placeholder image)

Comment: Hi Paul, coops has produced below basically what I'm after. With my code (or even with his), my icon and the text in the header keep sizing till they break out of their container and overlap content below the header. Can provide further info if helpful. Thanks - i_stack

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be your `float:left;` that's pushing everything out. You could try `display:flex;` on the banner div instead? I've amended your code below, have a look:

```css
.banner {
z-index: 1;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
height: 10%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #e5fbff;

display:flex;
}

.wrapper {
width: 30%;
max-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper p {
font-family: "Gentium Basic";
text-align: left;
display: block;
height: 100%;
margin:0;
}

.wrapper img {
max-height: 100%;
}

.ban1 {
padding-top: 50px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <span class="ban1" style="color:grey;">What</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">me</a>
    <a href="#">you</a>
    <a href="#">what</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">today</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Just changed the background colour of the banner to show you it is contained.

Comment: hmm... super curious. Yours does indeed seem to be performing as I'd like mine to even when I use your code - except perhaps with the exception of the img not sizing with screen sizing and the absence of a navbar but presumably these aren't essential to the successful working of your code. I don't have the div names you have (although I may change them to that) but presumably they aren't essential either.. 

I didn't include in my code a second line of text below the 'what' or the navbar, thinking they were irrelevant. Let me know if that isn't the case. 

Thanks for your help. i_stack

Comment: My img has also disappeared now (regardless of image size), ignore 'absence of navbar' in above comment. I don't suppose my use of masonry to arrange images below the header is relevant..  i_stack

Comment: @i_stack i'm not sure i understand your requirements. do you mind sending a link of your page, or pasting your content into a jsfiddle?
Do you have an image of what you'd like it to look like in the end? Maybe i could suggest an alternative way of achieving your end result.

Comment: Hey coops - I've created a jsfiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/L3mo6ghz/. Don't worry too much if not immediately apparent.

Comment: Grweat, thanks @i_stack. Is this the actual/final code you'd like to work with? I thought my answer pretty much satisfied the original question - could you explain a little clearer how else I could help?

Comment: Hey, yeah - that jsfiddle code is my application of your solution, which as you can see didn't work. If you're able to point out why it's not working in that example that would be great. Thanks and no pressure. i_stack

Comment: Hi @i_stack, I'm hoping this will help you! https://jsfiddle.net/thaug31k/. 

I have just added in "height:100%" to the image, 
and if you add ```align-items: center;``` to the banner, then you can remove all your ```vertical-align``` references as this will center everything nicely. 

(Have a read up on Flexbox, it will make a lot more sense if you know the basics!) :-)

I've amended your HTML too, as I thought there were a few unnecessary items in there. Please note, when naming an img source don't forget your quotes! <img src="___.jpg">

Comment: Thanks  coops - I note that I still seem to be able to zoom in on that jsfiddle example you provide to the point the words spill from the container but it seems nonetheless like simplifying the structure might be the way to go. Some of the additional html in there might account for there being a second of line of text beneath 'What' in my version, but even so it seems there's some fat to cut. I'll check out the flexbox too. Thanks again, i_stack

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope this codepen example will help you in responsive header with a image as follows: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZXREE

```
<header class="p-1 sticky-top">
    Refer the codepen for the code...
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks krsna - I think the simplified html structure is where coops and I landed too.